# .htaccess better url multiple "folders"

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

i am trying to use .htaccess file to rewrite the url so that i go from index.php?p=front to /front, and it works like a charm, but when i try to make multiple "folders" such as /forum/123123 (thread id) it shows me a no-css version of the index page. This is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?404
```

i check if `$_GET['404']` is set in the index, if so i handle everything. but it doesn't work since it just shows a no-css version of the index, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You'll need link your css relative to your web root

Comment: @ChrisW oh haha thank you! the problem wasn't that it wasnt working it was that neither the CSS nor the PHP includes was loading, therefor the "pagination" system i made wasnt displaying any text, giving the illusion that it was all just an empty no-css file! thanks! i fixed the css, any idea how to make a "php relative"?

Comment: @SimonAndersson: What do you mean by `any idea how to make a "php relative"?`